# what is ajaxOptions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I found this in some javaScript code:

```
ajaxOptions = {
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
       $('#revenue_paginator').html(data);
    },
    error: function(){},
    complete: function(xhr){ 
        onCompleteCheck(xhr);
        }
    };
```

I just want know what it is. I originally thought it was jquery but there is nothing inside the jquery documentation about it. Google searches direct me to questions that involve ajaxOptions but nothing as simple as what ajaxOptions is.

Comment: It's the options used for the jQuery ajax method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

`ajaxOptions` is an arbitrary name assigned by the developer, the important part is what is in the object and how it relates to jQuery, you can review the jQuery documentations for [`ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to get a better understanding.

> Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests.
>   version added: 1.1 jQuery.ajaxSetup( options )
>   options: A set of key/value pairs that configure the default Ajax request. All options are optional.

Answer (score 1):

`ajaxOptions` that you have is just an javascript object defining different configuration parameters that can be passed to `$.ajax` jQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

`ajaxOptions` just looks like a normal variable name to me.  You could do the following:

```
ajaxOptions = ...
$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```